How to programmatically select a base layer at runtime in HEREmaps?
I know I can define several base layers by customizing the MapSettingsControl object.
const mapset = new H.ui.MapSettingsControl({
    alignment: 'bottom-right',
    baseLayers: [{
        label: 'Map view [day]',
        layer: defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
    }, {
        label: 'Map view [night]',
        layer: defaultLayers.vector.normal.mapnight,
    }, {
        label: 'layers.satellite',
        layer: defaultLayers.raster.satellite.map,
    }],
});

ui.removeControl('mapsettings');
ui.addControl('mapsettings', mapset);

But how do I then pick it? There is no selectLayer() method anywhere, and the SDK doesn't seem to react to jQuery $('#map-view-night-tile-layer-option-button--gave-id-for-testing').trigger('click') events either.
I've found this my_map.setBaseLayer(defaultLayers.vector.normal.mapnight) method … 
https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/maps-api-for-javascript-api-reference/page/H.Map.html#setBaseLayer
… but if I do it like this, the tile layer options menu becomes unusable: that selected layer is now the permanent new singular base for all options. Upon user click on another option (like satellite), the other layer briefly pops in but is then immediately replaced by the one set in setBaseLayer().
That method doesn't accept integer index values either, which could have been referring to the list set in MapSettingsControl.

Never mind this question – this does seem to be the correct way to do it. My project just also has a refresh / rerender loop … and I've tied my new setMode() method unfortunately to it.
function setMode(mode) {
    // only once.
    if (map_mode === mode) {
        return;
    }

    map_mode = mode;

    if (mode === 'night') {
        my_map.setBaseLayer(defaultLayers.vector.normal.mapnight);

    } else {
        my_map.setBaseLayer(defaultLayers.vector.normal.map);
    }
}

